# how can I show name and value of Custom Fields together?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I know how to show name and value of all Custom Fields

```
<?php the_meta(); ?>
```

and I know how to show one Custom Field value

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "yourkey", false); ?>
```

But how to show name and value of one particularly Custom Field.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is concatenation with `.`

```
<?php

$key = "yourkey";

echo $key . ": " . get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, false );

?>
```